# Unable to route to controller within subfolder - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter.

I am creating an application where I have created controllers within sub folders.

```
Demo
 -Application
    -Controllers
      - Home
        -Left
        -Right
        -Main
```

In routes.php, I have added below line.

```
$route['Left/(:any)'] = 'Home/Left/$1';
```

This is the URL I am trying to access.

http://localhost/Voyager/left/main

I am getting "404 Page Not Found error".

Is there something else I need to add or change?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You added "Left/(:any)" with captial case "L" to routes.php. But you tried to call "Voyager/left/main" with small "L". You should call "http://localhost/Voyager/Left/main" or change 'Left/(:any)' to 'left/(:any)' in your routes.php

Comment: I tried doing that, but its not case issue. Still not routing

Comment: Please show the name of classes in controllers folder and the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Issue was that I had another controller in controller folder with name Home, which was causing issue. Renaming that solved the issue.